# The project name '.gradle' must not start or end with a '.'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i'm using android studio but whenever i'm using android studio this error happend

```
   A problem occurred configuring root project '.gradle'.
```

> The project name '.gradle' must not start or end with a '.'. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement

i'm tried to change gradel name but it doesn't resolve problem

how can i resolve this probelm??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have project directories starting or ending with a dot since then they will get hidden by default.

Please add the following code to your build.gradle to change the projects names:

```
rootProject.name = 'root'

include 'sub'
project(':sub').projectDir = file('.sub')
```

As a result, gradle will not throw an error and your project directories will still start with a '.'